# How can I populate a menu using intents?

Tags: android

How can I populate a menu using [intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)? I didn't understand that thing.

Or is there any better way for that?

#### Update:

Suppose I have an application that need to resize the image,and there are many other applications that have a capability of resizing the image. How can I show the list of applications on a menu in my application so that when clicking on a particular option it will invoke the intent associated with that application. Simply saying I could resize the image in my application with out bothering about how that will get done.

Comment: pls refactor your question. Your question and what I understand from your comments have nothing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example, using the onOptionsItemSelected that appears with the menu button you control what the menu does:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case HISTORY_ID: {
        AlertDialog historyAlert = historyManager.buildAlert();
        historyAlert.show();
        break;
      }
      case SETTINGS_ID: {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        intent.setClassName(this, PreferencesActivity.class.getName());
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
      }
}
```

But we create the menu with this code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, SETTINGS_ID, 0, R.string.menu_settings)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences);
    menu.add(0, HELP_ID, 0, R.string.menu_help)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help);
    menu.add(0, ABOUT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_about)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i mean is that possible to use intents to populate menu       For example, suppose i need to  implement a new image handling tool that shrinks an image to a smaller size it will offer this as a menu option to any other Activity

Comment: @Kariyachan - as I can understand, I will add it with OnCreateOptionsMenu, or use xml to create the menu. I suggest you remake the question, it is not clear, give examples, use other words.

Comment: @ netadictos-Okay,suppose i have a application that need to resize the image,and there is many other applications that have a capability of resizing the image. how can i show the list of application that on menu in my application so that when clicking on particular option that it will invoke  intent associated with that application. Simply saying  i could resize the image in my application with out bothering about how that will get done